# Росомаха - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Вообще, интересно было бы узнать происхождение всех названий зверей (некоторые тут уже рассматривались), но меня давно интересует слово «росомаха». Нет даже никаких ассоциаций, чтобы понять название, как можно, например, со словами «медведь» или «норка»! Может быть, слово происходит от какого-то диалектного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Славяне с угро-финнами ещё долго будут об этом слове спорить:
http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-11281.htm

> росома́ха
>   животное "Gulо borealis", укр. росома́ха, чеш., польск. rosomak. Зап.-слав. слова могут быть заимств. из русск., как и наверняка коми rе̮ssе̮mаk "росомаха" (Вихман–Уотила 223).
>   Лат. rosomacus, которое часто считают источником, не засвидетельствовано в ср.-лат. текстах и явно представляет собой нов.-лат. новообразование научного языка на основе зап.-слав. форм. По мнению Рясянена (ZfslPh 20, 450), из фин. *rosso-maha, аналогично rosso-suoli "толстая кишка" (Лённрот), от maha "живот, брюхо", suoli "кишка". Более затруднительно фонетически возведение к манси tolmaχ "вор, росомаха", ю.-ханты totmaχ, вост.-ханты i̯аlmаkΏ "разбойник", сев.-ханты totmaχ, lalmaχ "росомаха" (Кипарский, ZfslPh 20, 359 и след.). Нельзя производить начало слова росоI(маха) от и.-е. названия медведя, ср. др.-инд. ṛ́kṣas, авест. аrǝšа-, арм. arǰ, греч. ἄρκτος, лат. ursus, др.-ирл. art, вопреки Соболевскому ("Slavia" 5, 449). Нельзя также сближать с др.-исл. rosmhvalr "морж", норв. rossmål (см. о соответствиях Хольтß хаузен, Awn. Wb. 232; Маркварт, UJb. 4, 327), которые сближаются с д.-в.-н. rosamo "краснота".
>   (Росомаха могло произойти путем табуистической метатезы из *соромаха от слав. *sоrmаха, родственного нем. Hermelin "горностай", лит. šarmuõ, šermuõ – то же (см. Трубачев, ВСЯ, 3, 1958, стр. 120 и сл.), что, возм., подтверждается наличием укр. диал. сорома́ха (черкасск.) "росомаха"; см. КСИС, 28, 1959, стр. 89. – Т.)

М. Фасмер

Comment: Еще бы в этом словаре нормально по-русски было написано! А то вот что это: "которые сближаются с д.-в.-н."?

Comment: ***д***ревне-***в***осточно-...

Comment: Древневерхненемецкое. Это обычное обозначение для диалектов германских языков, среди которых выделяют верхне-, средне-  и нижненемецкие диалекты - по течению Рейна. Есть и нерейнские диалекты, но Фасмер на них меньше ссылается. А вообще вопросы надо задаваить в вопросах, комментарии - в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Росомаха славянского происхождения. Поскольку относится к семейству куньих, а куница - торговая марка меха на Руси, то:
Росомаха - rosomaxa > roso-mex> rus- mex - русский мех (слав.)